# Ruach Hakodesh when Naming a Child for an Ancestor?

Tags: names, baby-infant, arizal

The Arizal says that parents having a certain level of ruach hakodesh when naming their child.

> [Sha’ar HaGilgulim (23:8)](https://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA) - ונמצא כי כאשר נולד האדם וקוראים לו אביו
> ואמו שם אחד העולה בדעתם אינו באקראי ובהזדמן כי אם הקב"ה משים בפיו השם
> ההוא המוכרח אל הנשמה ההיא כמש"ה אשר שם שמות בארץ כפי מקום האבר שבאדם
> העליון אשר ממנו חוצב והשם הזה נרשם למעלה בכסא הכבוד כנודע ולכן ארז"ל
> שמא גרים

Does this ruach hakodesh apply even when naming one's child after an ancestor or only when considering a name without previous "obligations" or external pressure? (Perhaps the external pressure is min hashamayim too, but is there a source one way or the other?)

Comment: Worth considering- this is how most Jewish babies are named and has been for a long time

Comment: Many Sephardim name after living relaitives too. Based on this, since the Sephardic name selection is so wide even when naming after a relative, they must have more access to ruach hakodesh right? :)